# Objects are scaling along global axes instead of local (even after setting Transformation Orientation to “Local”)

Tags: transforms

Problem: objects are scaling along global axes instead of local, even though I set Transformation Orientation to “Local”.

The Transformation Orientation option seems to apply only to the graphic manipulator handles but not to keyboard scaling (key S). When using keyboard scaling, the object (such as cube), gets skewed because of this.

How to enable local orientation for keyboard scaling (key S)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do local scaling push <kbd>S</kbd> and then the axis you want to scale on twice.
So to scale along the local X you push <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>.

Comment: Perfect! I find it awkward that posting “thank you” is discouraged on Stack Exchange, especially when a new user like me is not allowed to upvote an answer. Since I don’t expect better answers, I’m selecting your answer as valid without waiting for others. Thank you!